Why is postgres not using my index on a json column?
I am trying to figure out why postgres stops using my index on a json field when i have a lot of data. Up to 1 million rows, it works fine and uses the index. But when I try the query on a table with 10 million rows, it switches to a full table scan, which of course is very slow.
I am on postgres 17 (docker image postgres:17.1-alpine3.20)
My table is defined as
CREATE TABLE auction_jsonb_indexed (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  start_date TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  end_date TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
  current_price INT DEFAULT NULL, 
  item JSONB NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE INDEX jsonb_author ON auction_jsonb_indexed ((item->>'author'));

I then generate test data with
TRUNCATE TABLE auction_jsonb_indexed;
INSERT INTO auction_jsonb_indexed (title, start_date, end_date, item)
SELECT
    'Title ' || cnt,
    '2024-01-01'::timestamp + (INTERVAL '1 minute' * (cnt-1)),
    '2024-01-01'::timestamp + (INTERVAL '1 minute' * (cnt+6)),
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
            'type', 'book',
            'genre', 'Genre '||cnt,
            'author', 'Author ' || cnt % 1000,
            'title', 'Title ' || cnt,
            'description', 'Description ' || cnt,
            'startDate', '2024-01-01'::timestamp + (INTERVAL '1 minute' * (cnt-1)),
            'endDate', '2024-01-01'::timestamp + (INTERVAL '1 minute' * (cnt+6))
    )::json
FROM generate_series(1, 10000000) AS t(cnt);

Now when i query, i end up with a full scan.
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM auction_jsonb_indexed WHERE item->>'author' = 'Author 1';

Finalize Aggregate  (cost=420329.21..420329.22 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=4248.623..4253.143 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=420329.00..420329.21 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=4248.436..4253.131 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=419329.00..419329.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=4237.667..4237.668 rows=1 loops=3)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on auction_jsonb_indexed  (cost=0.00..418285.94 rows=417222 width=0) (actual time=4.612..4228.083 rows=333333 loops=3)
                    Filter: ((item ->> 'author'::text) = 'Author 1'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 3000000
Planning Time: 0.108 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 14
"  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 0.837 ms (Deform 0.195 ms), Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.722 ms, Emission 12.087 ms, Total 14.646 ms"
Execution Time: 4253.505 ms

If i change the table to 1 million rows instead of 10, the explain shows that the right plan is made
Aggregate  (cost=3453.72..3453.73 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.921..0.922 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on auction_jsonb_indexed  (cost=16.12..3451.24 rows=993 width=0) (actual time=0.698..0.865 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((item ->> 'author'::text) = 'Author 1'::text)
        Heap Blocks: exact=1000
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on jsonb_author  (cost=0.00..15.87 rows=993 width=0) (actual time=0.446..0.446 rows=1000 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((item ->> 'author'::text) = 'Author 1'::text)
Planning Time: 0.115 ms
Execution Time: 1.045 ms

If i hack around with the configuration, i can get postgres to use the index.
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
SET enable_bitmapscan = OFF;

But of course that is not the solution - it just shows the index would be usable for the query.
I tried changing the statistics, but that did not help: ALTER TABLE auction_json_indexed ALTER COLUMN item SET STATISTICS 1000;
I made a db-fiddle, but it runs out of memory.
What do I need to change so postgres understands it can use the index?


You need to add the actual query you ran as text update to question. 2) Are those the complete EXPLAIN ANALYZE outputs? If not add them to question text as well.


Works perfectly fine on 10 million records:
  ->  Index Scan using jsonb_author on public.auction_jsonb_indexed  (cost=8.70..18263.60 rows=15999 width=0) (actual time=0.439..120.461 rows=10000 loops=1) Most likely you're using a default configuration, especially random_page_cost. Lower that one first to something that works for you.

Your fiddle doesn't run out of memory. It was pointing at a table with json instead of jsonb in the name: it works fine if you fix that. On your real setup, you also might've been manipulating one table then testing against a different one, which would explain why you didn't see any difference in the plan.

Your recipe above doesn't show the table getting a manual analyze.  Your fiddle does, but contains numerous other issues and so is unrunnable (even apart from the size limit imposed by the fiddle website).

thanks AdrianKlaver and jjanes , i realized the difference between EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN ANALYZE now. I updated the question.

thanks so much @FrankHeikens! the random_page_cost indeed was the issue! if i change that to 1.15 or lower, indexes are indeed used.

thanks Zegarek for pointing out the mixup in the fiddle. i fixed it now.
your fork uses the index because it has fewer rows. with 1M rows postgres uses the index, but with 10M it decides to rather to a full scan.

Thanks to the input from @FrankHeikens, i found the random_page_cost parameter. Indeed, lowering that value (to tell postgres its not that expensive to access random parts of the disk) makes postgres use the index.
I found that in my example on my system, for 10M rows, the value needs to be 1.15 or lower.
ALTER TABLESPACE pg_default SET (random_page_cost=1.1);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM auction_jsonb_indexed WHERE item->>'author' = 'Author 1';

Aggregate  (cost=10906.93..10906.94 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=4.152..4.154 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on auction_jsonb_indexed  (cost=87.60..10882.00 rows=9970 width=0) (actual time=2.803..3.858 rows=10000 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((item ->> 'author'::text) = 'Author 1'::text)
        Heap Blocks: exact=10000
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on jsonb_author  (cost=0.00..85.11 rows=9970 width=0) (actual time=1.465..1.466 rows=10000 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((item ->> 'author'::text) = 'Author 1'::text)
Planning Time: 0.076 ms
Execution Time: 4.271 ms

(Btw: Note that the number of different values in the indexed field also changes the plan. If I create the table with cnt % 10, a slightly different plan is used. It still benefits from the index, but is considerably slower.)
